# Looking for a cleaner way to implement this solution with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to Pandas and trying to put together training data for a neural net problem.

Essentially, I have 2 DataFrames:

One DataFrame has a column for the primary_key and 3 columns for 3 different positions (sports positions, for this example assume First Base, Second Base, Third Base if you'd like).  Each position has the player ID's for the player in that position.

On a second DataFrame, I have various statistics for each player like Height and Weight.

My ultimate goal is to add columns from the second DataFrame to the first DataFrame so that each position has the associated Height and Weight for a particular player represented as columns.  Then, I'm going to export this DataFrame as a csv, arrange the columns in a particular order, and use that for my training data, where each column is a training feature and each row is a training set.  I've worked out a solution, but I'm wondering if I'm doing it in the most efficient manner possible, fully utilizing Pandas functions and features.

Here's what my code looks like:
****EDIT:  I should point out, this is just a simplification of what my code looks like.  In reality, my DataFrames are being pulled from CSVs, not constructed from dictionaries created by myself.  ****

```
import pandas as pd  

dict_1 = {'primary_key' : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
          'position_1_ID' : ['ida', 'idb', 'idc', 'idd'],
          'position_2_ID' : ['ide', 'idb', 'idg', 'idd'],
          'position_3_ID' : ['idg', 'idf', 'idc', 'idh']
}

dict_2 = {'position_ID' : ['ida', 'idb', 'idc', 'idd', 'ide', 'idf', 'idg', 'idh'],
          'Height' : ['70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77'],
          'Weight' : ['200', '201', '202', '203', '204', '205', '206', '207']

}

positions = pd.DataFrame(dict_1)
players = pd.DataFrame(dict_2)


position_columns = ['position_1_ID', 'position_2_ID', 'position_3_ID']

carry = positions
previous = None
for p in position_columns:
    merged = carry.merge(right = players, left_on = p, right_on = 'position_ID', suffixes = [previous, p] )

    carry = merged
    previous = p

carry.to_csv()
```

After this code runs, I have a DataFrame which contains the following columns:

'primary_key'

'position_1_ID'

'position_2_ID'

'position_3_ID'

'position_IDposition_1_ID'

'position_IDposition_2_ID'

'position_IDposition_3_ID'

'Heightposition_1_ID'

'Weightposition_1_ID'

'Heightposition_2_ID'

'Weightposition_2_ID'

'Heightposition_3_ID'

'Weightposition_3_ID'

It's not pretty, but this gives me the ability to eventually export a csv with a particular column order, and it doesn't take a prohibitively long time to produce the DataFrame.

That being said, I'm doing this project partially to learn Pandas.  I would like to see if there are cleaner ways to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `melt`, `merge` and `unstack`:

```
df_out = carry.melt('primary_key')\
              .merge(players, left_on='value', right_on='position_ID')\
              .set_index(['primary_key','variable'])\
              .drop('value', axis=1)\
              .unstack()

df_out.columns = [f'{i}{j}' if i != 'position_ID' else f'{i}' for i,j in df_out.columns]
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
            position_ID position_ID position_ID Heightposition_1_ID Heightposition_2_ID Heightposition_3_ID Weightposition_1_ID Weightposition_2_ID Weightposition_3_ID
primary_key                                                                                                                                                            
a                   ida         ide         idg                  70                  74                  76                 200                 204                 206
b                   idb         idb         idf                  71                  71                  75                 201                 201                 205
c                   idc         idg         idc                  72                  76                  72                 202                 206                 202
d                   idd         idd         idh                  73                  73                  77                 203                 203                 207
```

Comment: Exactly the sort of input I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: @JcbRb Would you [upvote and accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top) this solution?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
height_dict = {k:v for k, v in zip(dict_2['position_ID'], dict_2['Height'])} 

weight_dict = {k:v for k, v in zip(dict_2['position_ID'], dict_2['Weight'])}

 positions = pd.DataFrame(dict_1) 

positions['p1_height'] = positions['position_ID1'].map(height_dict)
```

Similar steps for all the 3 ids for both height and weight.

You can loop, instead of writing repeated similar steps.

Hope this helps.

positions.to_csv()

Comment: Thanks for the input.  My DataFrames are actually from csv, I just wrote them out like I did in the OP because it was easier to see their structure that way.  I'll edit the original comment to clear that up.